# JBOSS: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I am moving a weblogic application to jboss.  This is the EJB3 application
- Installed jBoss (eap 6.1)
- removed all weblogic related annotations and use of jars from the project. 
  Recompiled everything and successfully created an ear file.
- Started JBOSS on local machine.
- Logged in to console, went to Manage Deployments (under initially created 
  Profile, that includes the data source).
- "Add deployment" is successful
HOWEVER !!
- When I do "assign" a deployment to a server group, I get the following error:

```
"step-2" => {
            "outcome" => "failed",
            "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {
                "jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-project.ear/my-project.jar#scsBDS\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-project.ear/my-project.jar#scsBDS\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: scsBDS] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: scsBDS] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionFactory]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate specified TransactionFactory class [org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory"
```

This error is repeated 3 times, as I have 3 datasources for this project.  But all of them were deployed to profile with no problem.

Changes between WL Version and JBOSS version
- I am using Java 7 in the project structure that I use for JBOSS, but when it 
  was on Weblogic it used java 5.
- I used hibernate 3.5 in the Weblogic structure, and am going with Hibernate 
  4.1 in this Jboss endeavor.  So, I suspect the issue is somehow here, because 
  hibernate 4 does not have JoinableCMTTransactionFactory class.
But, If I keep hibernate 3.5, I get the same error about its implemented interface - CMTTransactionFactory.

Any help?  please?

Comment: You can add Hibernate 3 as module, see: https://developer.jboss.org/en/jbossas/blog/2013/10/16/adding-a-hibernate-3-module-to-as-7

Comment: Thanks, @FedericoSierra .  But, thinking this way, should it not work, if I add hibernate 3 as a library in a project and then I implicitely have both 3 and 3 included in jboss installation?

Comment: The problem is that if you use JPA (persistence.xml) always being taken Hibernate 4, so you can change the default JPA implementation with `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:3"/>`

Comment: @FedericoSierra, thanks.  That was not the problem, but problem was in a  persistence.xml .. I left a references in properties there that wanted some weblogic related contextual classes.
It all resolved now, you pointed me where to look :)